# Is it possible to export emission with an .fbx file?

Tags: materials, export, .fbx

I made a model , some parts of that model have emission , I baked the emission into image textures. Is it possible to export this emission in the .fbx format? If so, then how can I do it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: What node setup are you trying? Hooking the image up the Emssion socket of the default Principled node should work.

Comment: I tried what you said and it worked , Thanks a lot scurest :)